# Why the ajax didn't partly refresh my page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, controller

I am using ajax with javascript to do a cancel or ship action. When I click the cancel link, there is no change in this page and I need to refresh the whole page to see the changed status. And nothing happens when click the ship link, even refresh the whole page. My jsp and controller code show as below:

JSP:

```
<script>
    var xmlHttp;
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try
        {
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e)
        {
            // Internet Explorer
            try
            {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e)
            {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }
    function cancelOrder(orderId, rowID){
        if (xmlHttp == null)
        {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }
        var query = "action=cancel&order=" + orderId;

        /* alert(orderId); */
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged()
        {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                var status = document.getElementById(rowID);
                alert(status.innerHTML); 
                status.innerHTML = "Canceled";
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "manageUserAccount.htm?"+query, true);
        /* xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); */
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return false; 
        /* var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row); */
    }
function shipOrder(orderId, rowID){
        if (xmlHttp == null)
        {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }
        var query = "action=ship&order=" + orderId;

        /* alert(orderId); */
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged()
        {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var status = document.getElementById(rowID);
                alert(status.innerHTML); 
                status.innerHTML = "Canceled";
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "manageUserAccount.htm?"+query, true);
        /* xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); */
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return false; 
        /* var row = document.getElementById(rowID);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row); */
    }

</script>

<c:forEach var="order" items="${user.orders}" varStatus="vs">
        <tr>
                <td>${order.id}</td>
                <td>${order.createDate}</td>
                <td>${order.status}</td>
                <td><a href="manageUserAccount.htm?action=viewDetails&orderId=${order.id}">View Details</a></td>
                <td><a onclick = "shipOrder(${order.id}, ${vs.index})">Ship the order</a><br><a onclick = "cancelOrder(${order.id}, ${vs.index})">Cancel the order</a></td>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller:

```
if(action.equals("cancel")){
        OrderDAO orderDao = new OrderDAO();
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("order"));
        Long orderId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("order"));
        Order order = orderDao.get(orderId);
        order.setStatus("Canceled");
        orderDao.save(order);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("cancel", "Canceled");
}
if(action.equals("ship")){
        OrderDAO orderDao = new OrderDAO();
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("ship"));
        Long orderId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("ship"));
        Order order = orderDao.get(orderId);
        order.setStatus("Shipped");
        orderDao.save(order);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("ship", "Shipped");
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, to check the response I always use:

```
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

Perhaps you are not getting the right status on your response?